# Signature Hash Key In Android

Tags: android, android-studio, sha

How to generate a signature hash key from android studio? I have a signed `.pepk` key with me for the current App.

Comment: please elaborate a bit more if possible, we won't know where you are facing problem and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @vikaskumar - i was trying to implement azure AD B2C integration on Android, so for registering the application, i need to have the `Signature Hash Key`. so they have provided a command telling this     ** keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64 **

Answer (score 2):

Write in terminal

```
gradlew signingReport
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok there is one option in android studio to generate the sha1 or sha256 or md5

here is where it's located

[image]

if you double click on the signingReport it will generate the hash's

something like this for every variant like debug release etc. take what. you need.

```
    Variant: debug
    Config: release
    Store: /user/path/release.keystore
    Alias: AndApp
    MD5: 08:E1:12:80:E4:B1:71:ED:AF:0B:1C:3A:72:F0:F2:3D:CC
    SHA1: BA:48:58:13:20:4B:03:76:4A:0C:E0:F8:18:14:3F:D0:92:CC:F1:D9:23
    SHA-256: BB:8D:D8:69:08:AA:7D:10:6F:BA:27:88:C7:B3:90:07:D7:C0:22:F3:C9:F8:C3:39:15:0E:54:78:3D:16:54:AB:34
    Valid until: Friday, 2 August 2022
```